# storage in tcl,using generated values for the same program?

Tags: tcl

I have a tcl code which generates some values for some arguments.now i want to store these values and use them with the same program but different arguments.how can it be done ?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Could you elaborate?

Comment: i want to use the value of a variable that is generated for the first time.during the second run

Comment: You could perhaps write the values to a file and then read the file to get them in the second run?

Comment: Jerry other than that is there any other option,which was what i was looking for?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know if there are any other way to do that. Maybe someone else could come and shed some light on that.

Comment: Perhaps you can post what your current code to help us understand your problem better.

Comment: You could also use the enviroment (set ::env(MY_VAR) value) to pass them.

Answer (score 1):

To store a value for later *in one run of the overall program*, put it in a variable.

```
set theVariable "the value is foo bar"
```

To store a value for later *in another run of the program*, you probably need to write it to a file. The simplest way is like this:

```
# To store:
set f [open theSettingsFile.dat w]
puts $f $theVariable
close $f
```

```
# To load:
set f [open theSettingsFile.dat]
set theVariable [gets $f]
close $f
```

Tcl being Tcl, you could also store it as a script that you can `source`:

```
# To store:
set f [open theSettingsFile.tcl]
puts $f [list set theVariable $theVariable]
close $f
```

```
# To load:
source theSettingsFile.tcl
```

For complex things, using a database like SQLite might be a good idea:

```
# To store:
package require sqlite3
sqlite3 db theSettings.db
db eval {CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS settings (key TEXT, value TEXT)}
# Note; the below is SQL-injection safe    
db eval {INSERT INTO settings (key, value) VALUES ('theVariable',$theVariable)}
db close
```

```
# To load:
package require sqlite3
sqlite3 db theSettings.db
db eval {SELECT value FROM settings WHERE key = 'theVariable'} {
    set theVariable $value
}
db close
```

But that's massive overkill for saving a single simple string.